# Sorting a vector with changes also made to another vector

Tags: matlab, sorting, indexing

Hey so I've so got a vector of doubles such as

```
A =

0.801803535307197   0.737925186997728   0.623273483797294   0.722046963741684   0.542990601252408   0.427383289758162   0.683274297039423   0.487075921796818   0.724212337440899   0.471205842265225   0.705330994860834   0.489516811267092   0.598658541230977   0.759194544103108
```

I've also got a corresponding vector list of char type data such as

```
B =

Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci velit
```

(Each double has a word)

I want to order the doubles numerically using the sort function (sort(A)), but I also want the sort to be carried out on the char list (in the same way) - How can I do this?

Many appreciation and thanks to you and your families

Comment: Have you looked at the [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) for the `sort` function? You can use the output argument to index into the 2nd vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some example to get you startet:

```
B = 'Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci velit';
B_list=strsplit(B,' ')
A = rand(size(B_list))
[a_sort, ix] = sort(A)

b_sort = [B_list(ix); repmat({' '},1,numel(ix))]
b_sort = [b_sort{1:end-1}]

B_list =  'Neque'    'porro'    'quisquam'    'est'    'qui'    'dolorem'    'ipsum'    'quia'     'dolor'    'sit'    'amet'    'consectetur'    'adipisci'    'velit'
A =   0.8147    0.9058    0.1270    0.9134    0.6324    0.0975    0.2785   0.5469   0.9575    0.9649    0.1576    0.9706    0.9572    0.4854
a_sort =    0.0975    0.1270    0.1576    0.2785    0.4854    0.5469    0.6324    0.8147     0.9058    0.9134    0.9572    0.9575    0.9649    0.9706
ix =  6     3    11     7    14     8     5     1     2     4    13     9    10    12
b_sort = Neque velit quisquam ipsum dolor qui porro adipisci dolorem quia sit amet consectetur est
```

Comment: this answer is really badly formatted. And actually if you remove all spaces in the input sentence, you should add them again in the output.

Comment: Done that like you proposed.

Comment: apart from the spaces, I added this line for you.